# Overnight debugging of a specific user

Tags: apex, batch, debugging, logging

Anyone find a way to extend the logging capability of the developer console, or perhaps an appexchange app that will allow extended exception logging for overnight batch apex and integrations?

Trying to record INFO level logging of a series of integrations, jobs, then triggers to trace an intermittent failure, but can't get more than 20 execution cycles (or aren't setting up the console correctly).

Any tips or ideas would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent you have control over your batch jobs, I would recommend that they log their activity to an SObject that is saved after the batch finishes - and especially after any code-induced rollbacks.

For example, in a batchable class, makes ure it implements `Database.stateful` and log interesting events, exceptions, etc into a String variable `log` that is written to a custom object `Log__c` in the finish() method.

You can log the query executed, exceptions thrown, and even replace any `system.debug(..)` statements with a new method `addToLog(thedebugmsg)` that appends with line breaks to stateful variable `log`

More detail on this approach (and a more robust solution) can be found in [`Advanced Apex Programming, second edition`](http://advancedapex.com/) by Dan Appleman, chapter 9

Comment: Excellent suggestion and reminder -- I've implemented this in the past but hadn't come to mind for this customer. Thanks!